# Procedure or function has to many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql

how are guys

i have problem with this error , and i hope you guys can help me

here : this is the procedure from sql server for updating my records

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATEnewsAR(@img varchar(max),@con ntext,@id varchar(10))
as
begin
update newsAR set img= @img , con = @con where  id=@id;
end
```

and here the code in C#

```
  public void updatefullnewsAR(string img ,string con ,string id)
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            conn.Open();
            comma.Connection = conn;

            comma.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comma.CommandText = "UPDATEnewsAR";

             comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
            comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@con", con);
            comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            comma.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

    }
```

thank you

Comment: Please show the complete error message, indicate where it occurs, and include declarations of the variables. Then we may be able to tell if your reusing a `Command` and adding parameters each time through the code.

Comment: it is suspicious that comma is not local to the function. i suggest you inspect it in debugger to,see which parameters are actually set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the parameter set on `comma` before adding the three you need. Put this after you call `conn.Open();` and after you call `conn.Close();`

```
comma.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: thank you a lot mrtig , and sorry because i can't vote up your answer because i dont have enough rating